# Add contacts to Outlook Distribution List

Tags: vba, outlook

I have 1000+ contacts each with a selection of common job titles. I'd like to programmatically add each job title group (e.g. all the contacts with the job title 'Managing Director') into a Distribution List (e.g. 'Managing Directors').

Comment: It's simple. What have you tried?

Comment: I'm trying some example from a book called the Outlook Programming Bible but none of them do quite what I want and I'm not having much luck modifying the code.

Comment: Rather than trying to fix code that maybe hideously wrong, would it not be easier for you to submit an answer?

Comment: I had no intention of fixing the code. I already have the code ready :) I will post it the moment I see an effort from your side :)

Comment: I've tried using the AddMembers method but I don't know how to specify the job title as the common factor rather than the contacts name.

Comment: So correct me if I am wrong, You want to create a Dist List first say 'Managing Directors' if it doesn't exists and then add the contact with `job title group - Managing Director' to that list. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I'm happy to create the DLists manually. I then want to add everyone who has the same job title to the DList. So for example all the people with the job title 'Accountant' will go into a DList called 'Accountants'.

Comment: Ok I wrote the code to create the DList so I will post that as well. Gimme few minutes to amend the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok here is an example for only the default Contacts folder. Similarly, you have to go to every folder where a DL might exist, starting with the default Contacts folder to check if the Dist List exists before creating it.

**TRIED AND TESTED (IN OUTLOOK VBA)**

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetJobList()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNmspc As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olAdLst As Outlook.AddressList
    Dim olAdLstEntry As Outlook.AddressEntry
    Dim olDLst As Outlook.DistListItem, olDLstItem As Outlook.DistListItem
    Dim olMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olRecipients As Outlook.Recipients

    Dim jobT() As String, JobTitle As String
    Dim i As Long

    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olNmspc = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    i = 0

    '~~> Loop through the address entries
    For Each olAdLst In olNmspc.AddressLists
        Select Case UCase(olAdLst.Name)
            Case "CONTACTS"
                '~~> Get the Job Title
                For Each olAdLstEntry In olAdLst.AddressEntries
                    On Error Resume Next
                    JobTitle = Trim(olAdLstEntry.GetContact.JobTitle)
                    On Error GoTo 0

                    If JobTitle <> "" Then
                        ReDim Preserve jobT(i)
                        jobT(i) = olAdLstEntry.GetContact.JobTitle
                        i = i + 1
                    End If
                Next
        End Select
    Next

    '~~> Loop through the job title to create the distribution lists
    For i = LBound(jobT) To UBound(jobT)
        '~~> Check if the DL List exists
        On Error Resume Next
        Set olDLst = olNmspc.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Items(jobT(i))
        On Error GoTo 0

        '~~> If not then create it
        If olDLst Is Nothing Then
            Set olDLst = olApp.CreateItem(7)
            olDLst.DLName = jobT(i)
            olDLst.Save
        End If
    Next i

    '~~> Loop through the address entries to add contact to relevant Distribution list
    For Each olAdLst In olNmspc.AddressLists
        Select Case UCase(olAdLst.Name)
            Case "CONTACTS"
                '~~> Get the Job Title
                For Each olAdLstEntry In olAdLst.AddressEntries
                    On Error Resume Next
                    JobTitle = Trim(olAdLstEntry.GetContact.JobTitle)
                    On Error GoTo 0

                    If JobTitle <> "" Then
                        On Error Resume Next
                        Set olDLst = olNmspc.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Items(JobTitle)
                        On Error GoTo 0

                        '~~> Create a mail item
                        Set olMailItem = olApp.CreateItem(0)
                        Set olRecipients = olMailItem.Recipients
                        olRecipients.Add olAdLstEntry.GetContact.Email1Address

                        '~~> Add to distribution list
                        With olDLst
                            .AddMembers olRecipients
                            .Close olSave
                        End With

                        Set olMailItem = Nothing
                        Set olRecipients = Nothing
                    End If
                Next
        End Select
    Next

    Set olNmspc = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
    Set olDLst = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi. I'm getting an error 91, object variable or with block not set on this line: olRecipients.Add olAdLstEntry.GetContact.Email1Address - I only have one contact and DList is correctly created and the contact does have an email1address. Any ideas?

Comment: I think it might be finding the DList that has just been created and treating it as a contact. Looking into a way of checking the contact type and if it is a DList to skip it.

Comment: Ok I got it working but the problem is that the contact isn't added to the DList, just their email address. So when the contact is updated with a new email address say, this change is not reflected in the DList when you click 'Update Now'.

Comment: I used the 'FileAs' property instead which seems to work. Thanks for your help :)