# Getting the representative email address of a distribution list

Tags: vba, list, email, outlook, contacts

How do I get the representative email address of a distribution list (NOT the email addresses of each member in the list)?
Please refer to the following pseudo code.

Your kind help would be appreciated.

```
Dim Recip As Outlook.Recipient
Dim Recip_email As String

If Recip.AddressEntry.AddressEntryUserType = olExchangeUserAddressEntry Then
    Recip_email = Recip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
ElseIf Recip.AddressEntry.AddressEntryUserType = olSmtpAddressEntry Then
    Recip_email = Recip.Address
ElseIf Recip.AddressEntry.AddressEntryUserType = olExchangeDistributionListAddressEntry Then
    ' Recip that is a distribution list seems to fall in this branch
    ' How do I get the representative email address of the group?
    ' Example: if the representing email address is aaa@aaa.com, Recip_email = aaa@aaa.com

    Recip_email = ??????????????????????

Else
    Recip_email = vbNullString
End If
```

Comment: What do you mean by "representative email address of a distribution list". The address of the DL itself?

Comment: Yes, the email address of the DL itself. The DL has an email address assigned to it just like a regular SMTP address.  Recip_email is an SMTP address. Refer to Recip_email in the code.

Comment: Have you checked this link: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637729/add-contacts-to-outlook-distribution-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Recip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeDistributionList.PrimarySmtpAddress`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21500841)

Comment: @user347383 this DOES provide an answer.

Comment: Dmitry@ Thank you and it works fine. However, there seems to be a syntax error in your code: Recip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeDistributionList.PrimarySmtpAddress

Comment: @Barok - yes, sorry, I fixed the answer.